# Joining DynamoDB tables with AppSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync

I have 2 types:

```
type Location {
    id: ID!
    room: Int
    title: String
}

type Populate {
    id: ID!
    locationID: ID!
    location: Location
}
```

I need to populate the `location` field when I call the GraphQL api. Locations are stored in DynamoDB. I know that a resolver is necessary but I haven't been a exactly how to write it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via AWS AppSync Console. When you try and attach a resolver to an existing field in your schema, AppSync gives you certain pre-defined resolver templates out of the box. You can use those to connect to your DynamoDB DataSource.

Refer to the [following documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/configuring-resolvers.html) to attach a resolver.

Alternatively, you can use [AWS Amplify](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/graphql?sdk=js) to use [@connection](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/graphql#connection) directive to specify relationship between your `Location` and `Populate` types. This will transform it into a fully descriptive CloudFormation template and create DynamoDB tables, give you CRUDL based queries/mutations. It will also scaffold Resolver templates for the same.